# Автоматический выбор видеокарты для Win приложения (программно)

Tags: windows

Хотелось бы узнать,

есть ли возможность задать программно (может, через реестр), какую видеокарту использовать для моего приложения?

Имеется ноутбук с видеокартой (*Intel Graphics*) и мощная видеокарта *Nvidia*. т.е. через контекстное меню могу запустить, а как просто (например, через ярлык с параметрами) не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Да это возможно

Технология называется nVidia Optimus [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

можно скачать с сайта Nvidia [NVIDIA SYSTEM TOOLS WITH ESA SUPPORT](http://www.nvidia.ru/object/nvidia-system-tools-6.08-driver-ru.html)

Вкладка с выбором видеокарты появляется в панели управления Nvidia  => Управление параметрами 3D 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

там же появится возможность выбора для каждого приложения какую видеокарту запустить

Так же  предоставлена дополнительная информация о том как сделать отображение сразу 2 видеокарт одновременно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: данной]

Ссылка на статью:[!ТУТ!](http://club.dns-shop.ru/Froloff/blog/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-Nvidia-Optimus-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA/)

Comment: вообще-то спрашивается о программном переключении